# A question about extreme points

Tags: functional-analysis

If the extreme points of the unit ball of $C[0, 1]$ are $\pm{1}$, where $C[0, 1]$ is the Banach space of all continuous real-valued functions on the unit interval, then what would the extreme points of the unit ball be if we considered all continuous complex-valued functions on the unit interval? Would the extreme points in that case include all complex numbers $z$ such that $|z|= 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extreme points would be all continuous functions $f$ with $|f(t)| = 1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Is there any resource I could refer to that might explain the reason for this?

Comment: Do you see that all of those are extreme points?  On the other hand, if $|f(t)| < 1$ for some $t$, $f+g$ and $f-g$ would be in the unit ball if $|g| < \epsilon$ and $g(t) = 0$ when $|f(t)| \ge 1-\epsilon$.